# Benefit of private final native vs private native

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I know the meaning of `final`.

Is there any reason or benefit to use `private final native ...` instead of `private native ...` when doing JSNI calls? The reason I ask is because I am not an expert in JSNI but I assume that adding `final` would be no different than if it were a non-native call. I have seen a lot of code use `private final native ..` and I am not sure of the motivation. Some code I am working on is using `private final native ..` and I am inclined to remove the `final` qualifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we talk only about GWT, than `final` keyword is only required on native methods in [JSO](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay) classes. Otherwise you should only follow standard Java practices, or your team specific practices. Some teams simply prefer to put final on anything that can be final (and usually IDE does this automatically for them) and there are good reasons to do so.

Comment: Two other simple notes: 1) If it is already `private`, then it cannot be overridden, so might as well be `final`. 2) The GWT compiler will make anything final that can be as part of its compilation process, so there is no need to use that as a hint for the compiler, only as a hint for developers and a self-bugcheck. Only case where it really matters: `JavaScriptObject` subtypes, where either the type must be final, or all methods must be final to allow the compiler to treat the object like a real JS object.